# Navigate View Controllers After Presenting First View

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa

I just changed my app and Im quite confused. It started with the root view that then pushed a second view, there is a button on that view that pushes another view...
So I decided to instead present that second view controller but now the other view cant be pushed from the second.

Code From Root View:

```
 //This works
 [[self navigationController] presentViewController:secondViewController
                                          animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Code From Second View:

```
 //This Does not work
 [[self navigationController] pushViewController:locactionView animated:YES];
```

Edit: Sorry for the lack of detail. No exception is thrown it simply doesn't push the "Location View." Before I presented the view I pushed it and everything worked fine. Also when the view was originally pushed the navigation bar was visible, now that the View Controller is being presented I can't push a view or see the Nav Bar. I hope this helps. I don't know what code I could add because I only changed a single line before the problem occurred.

Comment: What doesn't work?  It does not push the view controller?  Does it crash?

Comment: Can you share a little more code?

Answer (score 0):

In your AppDelegate you could initialize your NavigationController with the rootViewController first, and then you could push the viewControllers on the stack, that could solve your problem

```
YourNavigationController *yourNavigationController = [[YourNavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.firstViewController];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have your hierarchy set up like this:

```
self.rootViewController = [[RootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RootViewController"
                                                               bundle:nil];
self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.rootViewController];
self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

You should not have any issues with this stuff. Your issue might be that you are trying to push onto the navigation controller from a view controller you presented modally which you cant do

Comment: I dont understand what rootViewController is in this